# VBScript - Either getting object required or type mismatch errors

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

I have scoured the web and this site looking for an answer on this, so I would really appreciate some help.

I'm creating a VBScript to do some modifications to a user-specified Excel spreadsheet. I have the first part of my script working fine, but the second part is driving me nuts. I need it to search the first column for a value and, if found, delete the row. Right now I'm not worrying about the deletion statement--I'm doing testing by seeing if I can get the For Each statement to run properly as well as the If Then statement. Here's the specific block of code:

```
For Each cell in objSheet.Columns("A:A").Cells

        Set cell = objSheet.Columns("A:A").Cells

        If cell.Value = "60802400040000" then
            cell.font.bold = True

        End If

Next
```

I have tried many variations of this and cannot find the right combination. Initially I was getting an "Object Required" messages, and after reading a number of posts, found that I needed to put in a Set statement for cell, which I did. Now I am getting a Mismatch Type error message.

The funny thing is, before I put in the Set statement, the code would execute, but it would throw the Object Required error when I closed the spreadsheet. After adding it, the error for the Type Mismatch pops up immediately.

Most examples I keep finding on the web are for VBA, and I try to modify them for VBS, which I don't know very well. Any assistance anyone can give me will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are redefining `cell`, `cell` is defined automatically in the `For Each` statement.

Delete this line

```
Set cell = objSheet.Columns("A:A").Cells
```

This is an example from Help, unfortunately Help doesn't have any examples that uses `For Each`, only `For x = n to n` and other means. `For Each` is the right thing to do.

```
Set r = Range("myRange")
For n = 1 To r.Rows.Count
    If r.Cells(n, 1) = r.Cells(n + 1, 1) Then
        MsgBox "Duplicate data in " & r.Cells(n + 1, 1).Address
    End If
Next n
```

For vba to vbs, you have to create the object and use, as some objects are automatically available in VBA (like app object) - `Set exceldoc = CreateObject("c:\blah\blah.xls)` then to use `Set r = exceldoc.worksheets(0).range("MyRange")`.

Also you have to use constant values not names as vbscript can't look them up.

Comment: Thanks for your help, BambiLongGone. I appreciate you taking the time to answer my question. After thinking about it more, I decided to rewrite the script as an Add-in for Excel using VBA; however, I'll make note of your answer for future reference. Heh, I must say I like Python better than VB--much easier to understand. :)